# Retrieve current state from useReducer outside React component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am leveraging the `useReducer` hook with Context to create a Redux-ish state store supporting middleware.

```
const Provider = (props: any) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, {
    title: 'Default title',
    count: 0,
  });

  const actionDispatcher = makeActionDispatcher(
    dispatch,
    applyMiddleware(state, thunkMiddleware, callApiMiddleware, logger),
  );

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ ...state, ...actionDispatcher }}>
      {props.children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

Note that I am passing `state` to `applyMiddleware`:

```
const applyMiddleware = (state: {}, ...middlewares: Function[]) =>
  function dispatcher(dispatch: Function) {
    const middlewareAPI = {
      state,
      dispatch: (...args) => dispatch(...args),
    };
    const chain = middlewares.map((middleware) => {
      return middleware(middlewareAPI);
    });
    return compose(...chain)(dispatch);
  };
```

This works, but eventually I want to be able to work with async actions, so ideally I'd have something like `redux-thunk`:

```
function thunkMiddleware(store: Store) {
  return (next: Function) => (action: any) => {
    typeof action === 'function' ? action(next, store.getState) : next(action);
  };
}
```

Given the thunk middleware will be acting upon async actions, ideally we would be able to pass a function to retrieve the current state when needed - `getState` - rather than be forced to use state as it existed when the middleware was applied, which could be out of date.

Normally I would pass something like this down:

```
const getState = () => React.useReducer(reducer, {
    title: 'Default title',
    count: 0,
  })[0];
```

But if I pass that down to middleware to be invoked, I get an error indicating I can [only call hooks from React functions](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions).

Am I architecting things wrong? Am I not properly wrapping my head around hooks?

UPDATE: adding requested `makeActionDispatcher` implementation

```
export const makeActionDispatcher = (
  dispatch: React.Dispatch<any> | undefined,
  enhancer?: Function,
): ActionDispatcher => {
  const actionDispatcher: { [key: string]: (...args: any) => void } = {};

  Object.keys(actionCreators).forEach((key) => {
    const creator = actionCreators[key];
    actionDispatcher[key] = (...args: any) => {
      if (!dispatch) {
        throw new Error('ActionDispatcher has not been initialized!');
      }

      const action = creator(...args);

      if (enhancer) {
        const enhancedDispatch = enhancer(dispatch);
        enhancedDispatch(action);
      } else {
        dispatch(action);
      }
    };
  });

  return actionDispatcher as ActionDispatcher;
};
```

Comment: Something like https://github.com/jamesseanwright/roll-your-own-redux/blob/master/src/bindings.tsx#L33 ?

Comment: What your `makeActionDispatcher` looks like

Comment: @Federkun Looking at the implementation, it seems like it also impossible for any async operations to get the current state, only the state when dispatch has been augmented.

Comment: @fard added - but I don't know how germane it is to the question.

Comment: You are trying to use hooks outside of the react context. Hooks are designed in a way that you can only use them within a react functional component. In your case, since you need to handle the store changes outside of the component, you can try moving your state out to an external function and create a custom hook https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Answer (score 2):

Use the `useEnhancedReducer` hook introduced [here](https://transang.me/get-state-callback-with-usereducer/).

Then you will have something like.

```
const [state, dispatch, getState] = useEnahancedReducer(reducer, initState)
```

Because `dispatch`, `getState` will never change, you can pass it to some hook without adding them to the dependence list or store them somewhere else to call them from outside.

There is also version of `useEnhancedReducer` which supports adding middleware, in the same post.